# Add Badges with Item Count to my Navbar using Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am looking for guidance/examples on the best way to add a badge to my `<ul class = "nav navbar-nav">`

I would like this badge to display the Item Count for all of the projects on the page.

**views/projects/index.html.erb**

`<& @projects.each do | project | %>`

**views/layouts/_header.html.erb**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><%= link_to "Projects", projects_path %> <span class="badge">(current)</span></li>
```

I realize I will probably need a "total" variable for the projects.item_count.

Then I probably want to put that 'projects.total variable next to `<span class = "badge">projects.total</span>`

Looking for the proper/best way to go about all of this.

Comment: Can you calculate the item count in the console using Arel?  So something like `Project.joins(:items).count("items.id")`?  If so, you should be able to add that directly to your header layout with interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Added:

To get the total number of records for a model you simply call `.count` on the model class.

```
irb(main):004:0> User.count
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
=> 1
```

However this cannot be used on an association since the associated objects belong to an instance - not to the class. So `Project.items.count` does not work but `Item.count` does. The same applies to collections ( `@projects.items.count # error`).

### If you need the count of items for a project:

The simplest way would be to do:

```
<span class="badge"><%= project.items.size %></span>
```

We use [`.size` instead of `.length` or `.count`](http://rhnh.net/2007/09/26/counting-activerecord-associations-count-size-or-length) since it is smart in that it will not cause an additional SQL query if the items already have been loaded.

Note that `project` is an instance of Project.

If you intend to use the items on another area in your view you can use this with a [`.joins` or `.includes` query](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html).

```
@products = Product.joins(:items).all
```

### if you are not using the items...

If they are not loaded it will cause one extra SQL query per project. To avoid this you can use what are called counter caches.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project, counter_cache: true
end
```

> Although the :counter_cache option is specified on the model that
>   includes the belongs_to declaration, the actual column must be added
>   to the associated model.
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

You can create the column with the following migration:

```
$ rails g migration AddItemsCountToProjects items_count:integer
```

Comment: Great answer @maxcal.  Wouldn't it be `Project.items.size` at the top?

Comment: No. The items belong to an instance of Project not the Project class.

Comment: Hmm on re-reading the question it´s not completely clear if he wants the total number of items for all projects or per project or is just confused. Edited question.

Comment: Note that the links included are for Rails 4. The behavior of `joins` and `includes` is quite different for Rails 3 and you would have to refer to the 3.2 docs. Although 3.2 is ancient and insecure and you should make a priority of upgrading.

Comment: Yes, we have upgraded to Rails 4 for other projects and this one will be upgraded as well. Just happened to be in 3.2 for now, so I wanted to learn the technique for getting this to work. Great Answer though, thanks.